# Allow access to my server

Tags: internet, internet-explorer, firewall, forwarding

I have a server, did some of the programming myself. It ison my home network, but I need to be able to access it from anywhere over the internet. I have done the port forwarding like I am supposed to, but I still cant get to it from an outside computer. It just displays Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage. I don't know what else to do. I am on a Linksys WRT54G v8 router running ddWRT v24 micro firmware.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to consider:

- Does your server's IP change?  You'll want to set up a DHCP reservation so it always gets the same address.
- Does your ISP block incoming connections to port 80? (If this is HTTP.)  Try a different port.

Answer (score 1):

To access your computer from outside your local network, you need to use your **external IP address**, meaning that of the router. The router then needs to forward the connection to your computer.

if you don't have a static IP address, you can use [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/).
This site also explains very well the concepts involved - see the "Resources" section.

Answer (score 1):

There could be any number of problems based on the information given. However, here are some steps to start with. First, make sure that you can view your web page (I'm assuming that you are talking about a web server) from another computer on your own network. This will be using your local IP address (i.e. http://192.168.0.2/). If that works, then try accessing it across the internet with your public IP address. You say that you are using port forwarding, so you may have to specify the port in the URL: http://192.168.0.2:8080/

If you are still having trouble, try using a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, on both the server and client to see which packets are making it to the desired location. You may also consider checking your web server's error and access logs. Another obvious thing to check is your firewall to make sure that it is not blocking packets.

These are a start. I would recommend that if you are running your own server, you will probably want to learn a little bit about networking also. Take note of why a browser "cannot display the webpage". There is a big difference between a 404 error, a 500 error, and a "cannon reach server" error. Simply knowing the difference is a first start to solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you cannot access the server from its public IP from within your internal network, so perhaps try it from a neighbor's house or the like.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Is your router connected directly to your ADSL line? or do you have a primary router provided by your ISP?

In some cases people use to "chaining" routers to those provided by ISP, if it is your case, you should forward your port across both devices, I mean, the first one must forward the desired port to the second router and second router must redirect it to desired device.

If this is not your case, please check out follow steps:

1. I recommend to use a static private IP for servers
2. On Router: Forward port (Ex. 80) to your server private IP
3. Verify it is correctly opened with a port scanner from outside (Here is one based on Nmap: http://scan.syscom.com.mx)
4. If you have a dynamic public IP address, you should use a DDNS service as DynDNS.com.
5. To keep your public IP updated you have two options:
   a) Use your router DDNS feature (if any)
   b) Install and set "DynDNS Update Client" in your server (http://dyn.com/support/clients/)
6. Try out!

Good look!